# ASP.NET Razor Pages erro ao processar a requisição

Tags: c#, razor-pages

Estou implementando um exemplo utilizando o *[ASP.NET Razor Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio-code)* e ao tentar acessar a página *Index* tenho o erro de que ouve erro na requisição.

> Error. 
>   An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID:
>   0HLA7N3BM0ANB:00000001
>
> Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more
>   detailed information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed
>   applications, as it can result in sensitive information from
>   exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging,
>   development environment can be enabled by setting the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>Contacts</h1>
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var contact in Model.Customers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@contact.Id</td>
                    <td>@contact.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@contact.Id">edit</a>
                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="delete" 
                                asp-route-id="@contact.Id">delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a asp-page="./Create">Create</a>
</form>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RazorPagesContacts.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace RazorPagesContacts.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public IndexModel(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IList<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }


        public async Task OnGetAsync() 
        {
            Customers = await _db.Customers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();   
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            var contact = await _db.Customers.FindAsync(id);
            if(contact != null)
            {
                _db.Customers.Remove(contact);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToPage();
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No configure tem esse `if` `if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }`

Comment: Tem sim esse if

Comment: Já debugou? quando acontece o erro?

Comment: tem dois OnGet? não pode! ou seja, OnGet e OnGetAsync faz a mesma coisa e o erro acontece ai, então comente OnGet

Comment: Mesmo um sendo Async?

Comment: Sim ... !!! mesmo sendo Async e mesmo tendo um outro assinatura... Razor Pages tem essas inconveniencias

Comment: A lógica é: ele tem que executar somente um dos métodos? como está o dois o Razor Pages não sabe qual executar e ai da a exceção.

Comment: ?Deu certo?    ....

Comment: Deu certo sim, valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque o `Razor Page` não consegue saber em tempo de execução qual dos dois métodos `GET` ***criados no seu código***, ou seja, `OnGet` e `OnGetAsync` é para ser executado, resumindo não pode coexistir os dois ao mesmo tempo no código, porque fazem a mesma coisa, gerando uma exceção por causa disso.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Introdução a Páginas do Razor no ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio)
- [ASP.NET Core - Aplicativos ASP.NET MVC mais simples com Páginas Razor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/mt842512.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No `web.config` altere(ou adicione caso não exista) o value da tag `environmentVariable` para `Development`:

```
<environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
</environmentVariables>



<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json.Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name = "aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath = ".\Application.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab

Caso não resolva só avisar.

Comment: Eu não tenho em meu projeto um web.config, somente o appsettings.json.

Comment: Estou utilizando o vscode e criei o projeto usando o dotnet new razor

Comment: Criei em outra pergunta sobre como colocar em Development https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264319/5846