# ASP.NET Core IsDevelopment

Tags: c#, razor-pages, dotnet-cli

Ao criar um projeto com o *[dotnet cli](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x)*

> dotnet new razor -o RazorPagesContacts

Como faço para mudar a variável de ambiente para o modo de desenvolvedor ao rodar a aplicação utilizando o `dotnet run`.

Visto que no `Startup.cs` eu tenho

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
```

E nunca entra no `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` usando o `dotnet run`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para trabalhar com diferentes ambientes no .NET Core é necessário que você atribua o nome do ambiente na variável `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

**Prompt de Comando**

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

**Powershell**

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
```

Vale ressaltar que as alterações da variável de ambientes através da *Linha de Comando* ou *PowerShell* só ficará disponível até a janela ser fechada.

Para atribuir o valor dessa variável de ambiente de maneira global, você deverá atribuir o valor nas Váriaveis de Ambientes do Windows.

1. Acesse Painel de Controle > Sistema > Configurações Avançadas do Sistema
2. Clique em *Variáveis de Ambiente*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Clique em ***Novo*** e atribua o ***Nome*** e ***Valor*** da Variável de Ambiente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para mais informações, acesse [Trabalhando com Múltiplos Ambientes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa atribuir o valor de "Development" para a variável de ambiente ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT. Antes de executar "dotnet run" execute o comando abaixo:

**Console do CMD**

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

**PowerShell**

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
```

> Fonte: https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Usando o setx não funcionou usando o console do vscode.
No vscode funcionou com o $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"

Comment: Porque daí é powershell

Comment: Sim, podia por na sua resposta as duas opções, tanto pra o CMD como para o powershell